# get_template_directory() returns nothing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm doing some custom theme work for the first time and I want to use

```
<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/main.css
```

to access the CSS file. However, when this renders in the html, it renders as:

```
/main.css
```

It's possible I deleted whatever setting or option that Wordpress uses to derive this path. What logic does Wordpress use to determine what the template directory is?

As a test, I added this code:

```
DIRS:

Plugins
<?php plugins_url(); ?>
<?php plugin_dir_url(); ?>
<?php plugin_dir_path(); ?>
<?php plugin_basename(); ?>
Themes
<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
<?php get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>
<?php get_theme_root_uri(); ?>
<?php get_theme_root(); ?>
<?php get_theme_roots(); ?>
Site Home
<?php home_url(); ?>
WordPress
<?php admin_url(); ?>
<?php site_url(); ?>
<?php content_url(); ?>
<?php includes_url(); ?>
<?php wp_upload_dir(); ?>
Multisite
<?php get_admin_url(); ?>
<?php get_home_url(); ?>
<?php get_site_url(); ?>
<?php network_admin_url(); ?>
<?php network_site_url(); ?>
<?php network_home_url(); ?>
```

and it rendered as:

```
DIRS:
Plugins
Themes
Site Home
WordPress
Multisite
```

So it's pretty clear that I messed up something Wordpress needs to determine it's directories. But I can't find anything in Google about how Wordpress comes up with these paths and the source code isn't obvious to me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_template_directory`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) *returns* a string. [It doesn't echo that string](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/theme.php#L256). This is very common behavior for WordPress functions that start with `get_`. Try:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/main.css
```

Comment: Yes, this does appear to be the answer. I'm new to PHP and I guess still a little confused about why this doesn't echo a string when <?php get_header(); ?> does seem to, but now that I know what my problem is, I should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you plan to do, you can also use:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```